# Payment Methods to purchase Audio Song/Album In iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, apple-developer

I need help, working on Music App where user can buy individual Song or full Album. can we offer different payment methods like Apple Pay,Google Pay,PayPal and Cards to purchase that song/album. Will apple approve it? because in their documents they mention to use In APP Purchases (IAP) for digital contents. But here our requirements is to purchases songs/albums using different payement Methods except In App Purchases.
We are handling app Plans subscriptions with In App Purchases (IAP).

Comment: Apple's guidelines are pretty clear. If the content is delivered digitally, in the app, you must use in app purchase. If you are shipping physical cds then you must use some other payment process.